# feature extraction using PCA

Tags: pca

My job is to perform gesture recognition. I want to do that by training a support vector machine using the features extracted by performing PCA(Principal component Analysis).
But I'm getting a little confused about the procedure.

After going through various articles, I've figured out these steps.

1. Take 'd' number of images(n*n) of the same gesture.
2. Convert each n*n image into a sigle row.
3. Form a matrix of order d*(n*n).
4. Compute the eigen values & eigen vectors.
5. Use top 'k' eigen vectors to form a subspace.
6. Project the image from original n*n dimension to 'k' dimension.

Question:

1) I have a set of 100 gestures and performing above 6 steps will give me 100 subspaces.My testing should be done on a realtime video to find which class a gesture falls in. Onto which supspace do I project each video frame to reduce the dimension for feeding it to the classifier?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you clarify what kind of gestures you are talking about? You mention video so I assume this is hand/body gestures. Do you have some intermediate system that does feature identification (e.g. finger/hand/eye position)? Or are you going to work with frame-by-frame pixels?

Comment: Yes, its hand gestures. My intermediate system segements the region containing hand, makes it a binary image, rotates it to align verticaly & then scales within a window of size 32*32. Then I'm trying to perform PCA to reduce the dimensions for feeding it to a classifier.

Comment: Just shooting from the hip here. I've done pen gesture recognition, which is similar but perhaps simpler. You asked which space to project the frames to. Maybe you'd get better mileage if you did some additional processing before doing PCA. So you've got bitmap images, which is similar to pen input recognition. See Tom Ouyang's paper (IJCAI 2009) for more on that. The difference here is you're working with dynamic information---so, left-to-right may have different meaning than right-to-left. His approach involves breaking the image (32x32 for you) into several subimages and doing pca on that.

Comment: I just figured out tha its silly to ask onto which subspace I project each video frame. That's because if I know that subspace I know the class of that gesture. 

So the approach should be like this: form a covariance matrix from the set of images representing all variations of all gestures. But doing so, inter class separation becomes lesser. So, further I'm thinking to form a decision tree to classify similar shapes to go into one branch, thus reducing the number of gestures to discriminate.

For further reading, http://www.face-rec.org/algorithms/PCA/jcn.pdf

Comment: This one has given implementation details http://dasl.mem.drexel.edu/~noahKuntz/openCvPart05.pdf