# PCA + shape descriptors - OpenCV

Tags: opencv, classification, pca, feature-descriptor

I am working on a hand gesture recognition, where I want to recognize numbers (n numbers of fingers up). I am comparing different descriptors (convex hull, chain code, fourier and moments) and different classifiers (bayesian, kNN and SVM). I wanted to know if I can use PCA as an intermediate step to reduce to feature set. I am unable to figure out how to pass, say a chain code, to PCA input.

Comment: If you can transform the features into a real vector, then yes, otherwise no. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6592804/feature-extraction-using-pca?rq=1

Comment: thanks for your reply!
I have seen this post, but this I have already been able to achieve that so far.. I can input the image vector to PCA and to a classifier and able to recognize the class correctly. But I wanted to know if instead of image vector, can I pass a descriptor vector?

Comment: You can, you can do PCA on any kind of vectors to reduce dimension. But based on your feature set, I really don't think you will gain much using PCA.

Comment: Yes, I was arguing the same thing with my colleague. Because feature set like convex hull already have very little information, there is not no need to reduce dimension. 
But in case I want to apply PCA, how can it be done? Because chain code or convex hull will have different dimensions for every image right? Can you please explain the process. Basically in what format should these descriptors be brought into to fed it to PCA?

Comment: This is a reply I got related to the query - pca is only for dimensional reduction large image data analysis as component data lies in linear quadrant and un-correlated data in the diagonal. chain code only for preserving boundary features of object for shape analysis